# How to read External storage files or folders using OTG cable in android

Tags: android, file, directory, android-external-storage

Can any one tell me how to read Files or Folders from external devices 
(**like pendrives, External HardDisk etc.,**) connecting via OTG cable and show those folders or files in listview in android.
I did search a lot regarding this, but couldn't find any clear idea.

Can any one please help me to achieve this concept? Just by giving suggestions atleast!

Comment: The same way as you do with files and folders on usual places. Well mostly. But... what is the problem you encountered?

Comment: where im getting ambiguation is, if the android device already got Sdcard itself, when we connect one more external device via OTG cable  then which files or folder can get access? either from SD card or from External device?

Comment: `then which files or folder can get access`  ???? So what do you want to know exactly? Your problem description is too vague.

Comment: You do not have arbitrary access to removable storage: https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html.